# finding the sum of the series till n values

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

when i was trying to solve a problem in finance aimed at calculating the final value I got this series But I am trying to find some other way to simplify this series 
Though I have tried it for $n=3$
$$M=x+xy+(x+xy)y+(x+xy+(x+xy)y)y$$ 
$$M=x(1+y)(1+y+(y+y^2))$$
$$M=x(1+y)(1+y)(1+y) $$
the sum will be 
$$M=x(1+y)^3$$
how can it be proved for n number of terms

Comment: By induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_{n+1} = x_n(1+y)$ which represents  a geometric sequence. If $x_0 = x$ then $x_n=x(1+y)^n$.